# I am having problems showing my offline users. I am not sure why my if statement is not working. Is there something wrong with my if statement?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xampp

This is the partial code.

```
if($_POST["action"] == "fetch_data"){
        $output = '';
        $query = " SELECT login.user_id, login.username FROM login_details INNER JOIN login ON login.user_id = login_details.user_id WHERE last_status > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)";
        $statement = $conn -> prepare($query);
        $statement -> execute();
        $result = $statement -> fetchAll();
        $count = $statement -> rowCount();
        $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                                    <div align="right">
                                        '.$count.' Users
                                    </div>
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-dark">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="50%">Username</td>
                                            <th width="10%">Status</td>
                                            <th width="10%">Action</td>
                                        </tr>';


   foreach($result as $row){
         $status = '';
         $current_timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d- H:i:s') . '- 10 second');
         $current_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_timestamp);
         $user_last_activity = get_user_last_activity($row['user_id'], $conn);
         if($user_last_activity > $current_timestamp) {
            $status = '<span class="label label-success">Online</span>';
         } else {
             $status = '<span class="label label-danger">Offline</span>';
         }
         $output .= '<tr> <td>'.$row['username'].' '.count_unseen_message($row['user_id'], $_SESSION['user_id'], $conn).' '.fetch_is_type_status($row['user_id'], $conn).'</td><td>'.$status.'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs start_chat" data-touserid="'.$row['user_id'].'" data-tousername="'.$row['username'].'">Start Chat</button></td></tr>';
    }

          $output .= '</table></div>';
          echo $output;
         }

    function get_user_last_activity($user_id, $conn) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY last_status DESC LIMIT 1";
        $statement = $conn -> prepare($query);
        $statement -> execute();
        $result = $statement -> fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            return $row['last_status'];
        }
    }
```

[This is the result when it's working. It just shows my online user whereas I want to be able to show both online/offline users at the same time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNVYP.jpg)

Is there something wrong I did?

Comment: Using `prepare/execute` without placeholders still isn't a true prepared statement, so you're still open to injection. You can just use `query()` instead but that wouldn't be safe.

Comment: That would depend on what the value of `$user_last_activity` is. We cannot discern  that from this code. Please provide the actual value of the variable in your question.

Comment: `strtotime(date('Y-m-d- H:i:s') . '- 10 second')` -- is that extra `-` after `Y-m-d` really in your code? strtotime would return false and `$current_timestamp` would be `1970-01-01`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query